# In Excel how to make a number like 4.246 be shown as a 4.25 permanently?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel how to make a number like 4.246 shown as a 4.25 permanently and not be shown 4.246 in *formula bar*?

Comment: Are you asking how to round the number? Are you asking how to keep the number as 4.246 but display it with only two (rounded) decimal points? Are you asking how to edit the cell so that it changes from 4.246 to 4.25?

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

Select the cells to be fixed and run this short macro:

```
Sub FixData()
   Dim r As Range

   For Each r In Selection
      r.Value = CDbl(r.Text)
   Next r
End Sub
```

This macro will change the underlying value to match the displayed value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't state if you want this value to be changed for a specific cell, or for any cell. Nor do you state if you just want all numbers to be rounded by 1 significant figure.

I'll assume you want the 1 cell rounded. You can change the number of decimals

[image]